# Automatically email the recent changes for a particular build in Hudson

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

Is there any way to send an email in Hudson which has the list of recent changes in that build?

For example

Trigger a build and if you go recent changes there we have some recent changes.  Once it is success, the email should have the list of the changes that happened in that particular build. After this, say the next build fails (build fail email will be triggered), but it records the changes and these change lists also should be included in next successful build.

Answer (score 3):

You'll first need to install the [Email-ext plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org//display/HUDSON/Email-ext+plugin) for Hudson.

Inside the project configuration, under **Post-build Actions** click the **Email Notification** and **Editable Email Notification** checkboxes.  Instead of having the *Content* be $PROJECT_DEFAULT_CONTENT you'll want to use a different token.  Those are described when you click the help icon (?) for *Content Token Reference*.

Specifically to your example, add (or edit if it exists) the trigger for Success.  Change the Content of the success email to use the token **${CHANGES_SINCE_LAST_SUCCESS, reverse, format, showPaths, changesFormat, pathFormat}**.  The different options are explained in the reference.  If you just want the defaults, simply use ${CHANGES_SINCE_LAST_SUCCESS}